# Type Script Randomiser With History Function

Tags: typescript

How would I display a "Previous Array" So every-time someone clicks a button it generates a new array.

I need to show every Previous Iteration I tried something like:

```
count = 0;

console.log(this.count);
      if(this.count >= 1){
        this.recentlist = [
         miditem,topitem,botitem,harditem,softitem
        ];
      this.count = 0;
      }
      else{
        this.count++;
      }
```

But this doesn't work great.

So every-time the button is clicked it pulls a random item from all my Hero lists then i get an item for all 5 of my variables. So it's a Randomiser Essentially but I want to show the Previous version of that Array.

```
 recentlist = [];

   if(midfine && topfine && botfine && softfine && hardfine){
      this.midhero = miditem;
      this.tophero = topitem;
      this.botHero = botitem;
      this.hardShero = harditem;
      this.softShero = softitem;

      this.recentlist = [
         miditem,topitem,botitem,harditem,softitem
      ];
  
    }
    else{
      this.createHeroes();
    }
```

```
      <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let item of recentlist">
          {{item}}
        </li>
      </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved this in a bit of a weird way.

Sharing for anyone having the same thought

```
this.temprecentlist = [
        "Mid " + miditem, "Offlane " + topitem, "Safelane " + botitem,"Pos 4 " + harditem,"Pos 5 " + softitem
      ];

        localStorage.setItem(this.count.toString(), JSON.stringify(this.temprecentlist));
        var getlist  = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(this.count.toString()));

        if(getlist = this.count){
          var tempcount = this.count - 1;
          var getnewlist  = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(tempcount.toString()));
          this.recentlist = getnewlist;
        }
        else{
          this.recentlist = getlist;
        }
      
       this.count++;
```

I created an extra list called temprecentlist, Added the Item's to it.

Saved it to local storage then I would Index the save to get list 1,2,3 ect.

Then I need to see what list wants to be displayed  this will usually be the same list as the Current count list so if I saved list 1 it'll be list 1 it wants to fetch so then I need to see okay if it's list 2 now but I want list 1 then I just check if the count is the same as the list Index

So if count is 1 and list index is 1 then:

then Fetch again but this time take the current "Count" and -1.

Essentially giving me the Previous list of every one I create so this list will always be one behind the main list being displayd.

And also not display on the first roll